# How do you make a bar a different color in KendoUI bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik, kendo-ui

I'm am replacing my dot net charting with KendoUI. I'm showing a Score Distribution chart. I want all of the bars to be the same color except the bar with the median score and the Legend. How do I color a single bar a unique color? How would I color the Legend this new color?

Below is my old dotnet charting bar chart and below that is the new KendoUI chart I'm trying to replace it with. I just need to get that coloring right and we'll be in business. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Update: I'm leaving the answer below this line intact in case there are those out there who are using an older version, but [per a later comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472084/1336699), KendoUI now allows you to override styles for individual points in a series.

---

I don't believe you can, in the current version. That said, you can hack your way around the limitation.

You'll need to create two data series - one for your highlighted data, and one for everything else. Add both to you chart, and set them to stacked.

Here's a jsFiddle I put together to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/LyndsySimon/9VZdS/. It depends on KendoUI's CDN, so if it breaks in the future I apologize.

Here is the Javascript for reference:

```
$(function() {
    var dataset = new Array(1,2,3,null,5,6);
    var highlighted = new Array(null,null,null,4,null,null);

    $('#chart').kendoChart({
        theme: 'metro',
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: 'column',
            stack: true
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Not Highlighted',
                data: dataset,
                color: '#609'
            },
            {
                name: 'Highlighted',
                data: highlighted,
                color: '#f03'
            }
        ]
    })
});​
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the work around. You get a +1 and when my 22 hours is up I will award you the bounty. I would suggest getting a real account for that ;)

Answer (score 15):

Starting with the 2012 Q2 release, bar series support binding the point color to a data item field.

This is done through the [colorField option](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#seriestype=%22bar%22colorfield-string). The [Binding to local data](http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/bar-charts/local-data.html) online example demonstrates it.

Both the Kendo UI and the legacy wrappers for ASP.NET MVC expose it as an option:

```
.Series(series =>
{
    series.Bar(model => model.Value, model => model.Color)
        .Name("United States");
})
```

All series overloads can be seen [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/ChartSeriesFactory).

Comment: Excellent. I've updated my accepted answer to point to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could hack the SVG generated by the system.  I have supplied the chart with a model which contains the colour for each bar. eg:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public decimal Score { get; set; }
}
```

Which is used as a series on the chart.  The view then looks like:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Chart(Model)
    .Name("AverageScores")
    .Theme("Simple")
    .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height: 500px"})
    .Series(series => series.Column(s => s.Score).Name("Name").Color("Blue"))
    .SeriesDefaults(sd => sd.Column().Labels(l =>
                                                 {
                                                     l.Visible(true);
                                                     l.Format("{0}%");
                                                 }))
    .Title("Mean Percentage Scores")
    .Legend(builder =>
                {
                    builder.Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom);
                    builder.Visible(false);
                })
    .CategoryAxis(ca => ca.Categories(x => x.Code))
    .Tooltip(builder =>
                 {
                     builder.Visible(true);
                     builder.Format("{0}%");
                     builder.Template("<#= dataItem.Name #><br/><#= value #>%");
                 })
    .ValueAxis(va => va.Numeric().Labels(a => a.Format("{0}%")).Min(0).Max(100)
    )
)

@section BelowTelerikScriptRegistrar
{
 <script type="text/javascript">


    function setAverageScoresColours() {
        var data = $('#AverageScores').data("tChart").options.series[0].dataItems;
        if (data != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var averageScore = data[i];
                $($($('div#AverageScores svg g')[i]).children('path')[0]).attr('fill', '#' + averageScore.Colour);
                $($($('div#AverageScores svg g')[i]).children('path')[0]).attr('stroke', '#' + averageScore.Colour);
            }
        }
    }

     $(document).ready(function () {
         setAverageScoresColours();
     })
 </script>
}
```

The section BelowTelerikScriptRegistrar must happen after the Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar() is called.

This will work in Chrome, Firefox and IE10.  I have noticed there is a problem with multiple chart and the timings around the generation of the SVG.  Unfortunately you might have to wrap setAverageScoresColours() in a setTimeout function to ensure the SVG has been generated, but it seems to work with just one chart.

A bit hacky, but easier than managing lots of series.

And for KendoUI (which I have edited for...):

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>

 <script>
 function createChart() {
     $("#chart").kendoChart({
         theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
         title: {
             text: "Internet Users"
         },
         legend: {
             position: "bottom"
         },
         seriesDefaults: {
             type: "column"
         },
         series: [{
             name: "World",
             data: [15.7, 16.7, 20, 23.5, 26.6]
         }],
         valueAxis: {
             labels: {
                 format: "{0}%"
             }
         },
         categoryAxis: {
             categories: [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]
         },
         tooltip: {
             visible: true,
             format: "{0}%"
         }
     });
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {
     setTimeout(function () {
         // Initialize the chart with a delay to make sure
         // the initial animation is visible
         createChart();
         $($($('div#chart svg g')[0]).children('path')[0]).attr('fill', '#123');
         $($($('div#chart svg g')[1]).children('path')[0]).attr('fill', '#321');
         $($($('div#chart svg g')[2]).children('path')[0]).attr('fill', '#213');
         $($($('div#chart svg g')[3]).children('path')[0]).attr('fill', '#312');
         $($($('div#chart svg g')[4]).children('path')[0]).attr('fill', '#132');
     }, 400);
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do it at runtime is using function which returns color.

[API reference](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.color)

Here is an example code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2],
    color: function(point) {
      if (point.value > 1) {
        return "red";
      }

      // use the default series theme color
    }
  }]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with current KendoUI version.

It's on their todo-list.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/dataviz/chart/change-bar-column-color-for-each-point.aspx

There can be a kind of workaround, as said in the thread I've put here, it would be to describe a series for each color you need. It looks very inefficient to me, but it's currently the only way to do it. If you have only 1 chart, you could do it. Else, wait for a new version of KendoUI with this feature.

Comment: If you had to do this a lot, LaGrandMere makes a good point. I'd create a wrapper function and extend Kendo's configuration options to handle this.

Later, when Kendo introduces this feature you could just refactor the wrapper to use the native implementation and move on with your day.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik have recently released a Kendo UI Data Vis Theme Roller

http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/dataviz.html