# Kendo Chart Bar color is not changing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

[image: Here is an image of my chart.]

The above image is of my chart.

The default color of this kendo chart is not changing - I tried to set the color but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Chart(item.UsageData)
                .Name(item.Type)
                .ChartArea(ca => ca.Background("transparent").Height(380))
                .Legend(l => l.Visible(true).Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom))
                .Series(s => s.Column("Cost", "lblUsage").Labels(l => l.Visible(true).Template("$ #= value #")))
                .CategoryAxis(x => x.Categories(item.UsageData.Select(y => y.lblUsage)).Labels(l => l.Rotation(-25)).MajorGridLines(m => m.Visible(false)).MinorGridLines(minor => minor.Visible(false)))
                .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Template("#= dataItem.lblUsage #: #= value # $").Padding(5).Background("#3893ae"))
                    )
```

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/local-data-binding, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10177619/4229270, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18584266/4229270

Comment: I have already tried SeriesColor but Bar color is not changing only legends color are getting changed. Color Problem is only with Bar and column Chart.